# Ruby on rails running javascript code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have to use this in my rails project.

http://nv.github.com/objectDiff.js/

So I added the entire folder to the app/assets/javascript folder and added

//= require objectDiff in the application.js file.

But when I try to access the objectDiff.dif method, it says that there is no such method.
I am new to rails. So please let me know if what I am doing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Move *objectDiff.js* into assets/javascripts/ 
Move *objectDiff.css* into assets/stylesheets/

Then require the above files in their corresponding application files :

*application.js* :

```
//= require objectDiff
```

*application.css* :

```
*= require objectDiff
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am stil gettng the same error. I m trying to access the method from my views like this objectDiff.diff(ver1, ver2). 
But it shows the error
"undefined local variable or method 'objectDiff'